# how do I put conditional within sprintf

Tags: php

I'm echoing the results of a query with this loop:

```
 $cds = toArray($result->GetClassDescriptionsResult->ClassDescriptions->ClassDescription);
 foreach ($cds as $cd) {
    $cdsHtml .= sprintf('<p><strong>%s</strong><br />%s<br />%s</p>', $cd->Name, $cd->Description, $cd->Prereq);
 }

 echo($cdsHtml);
```

This is displaying a list of classes.  There is a parameter called `$cd->ScheduleType`and that can either be `"DropIn"` or `"Enrollment"`.  Currently it is displaying both types.  I want to only display `"DropIn"`.

I tried this:

```
 $cds = toArray($result->GetClassDescriptionsResult->ClassDescriptions->ClassDescription);
     foreach ($cds as $cd) {
// conditional
if ($cd->ScheduleType="DropIn"){

        $cdsHtml .= sprintf('<p><strong>%s</strong><br />%s<br />%s</p>', $cd->Name, $cd->Description, $cd->Prereq);
     }

}
echo($cdsHtml);
```

But that did not filter out the other kind and also gave me lots of duplicates of all the classes for some reason...Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: replace `($cd->ScheduleType="DropIn")` with `($cd->ScheduleType=="DropIn")`

Comment: You're forgetting `==` vs `=`

Comment: Thank you-I just looked closer at the returned data and I'm seeing that the condition I need to account for is actually in the next level down in the data (I'm sorry I don't know the right words to describe what I mean).  I am going to edit my question to better explain.

Comment: Joel, make sure you don't change the question to the point all answers are now invalid. Your specific problem is the use of `=` instead of `==` and that's answered your current question. A different question should _be_ a different question.

Comment: Actually this whole question should be closed as it's off topic and basically  caused by a typo. As it is, this will likely never help anyone in the future as it really has nothing to do with the question at hand

Comment: Fair enough.  I accepted the first response.

Comment: Man what's with all the down votes in SO these days?  Off Topic?  A specific coding question?  Yeah-it was a typo...Isn't that what errors often are?  ok-just read that typo error are OT.  Sounds good.  Feel free to close...

Comment: Mainly because people don't take the time to check their own code for simple mistakes... You could just delete/close your own question

Comment: "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($cd->ScheduleType = "DropIn") {
```

should be entered as:

```
if ($cd->ScheduleType == "DropIn") {
```

The valid comparison operators are found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), and `=` is nowhere to be found.

What you're doing is [assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), which basically sets `$cd->ScheduleType` to `"DropIn"`, then uses that value as the `if` condition. Since that value is truthy (see "Converting to boolean" [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)), it always executes the `if` body.